# Which is grammatically correct in this sentence for a character's "declaration" so to say?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, sentence

Examples:

> Through selfless duty, devoted communication, and new experiences will
>   I strive to grow my connections and understand those around me.
>
> Through selfless duty, devoted communication, and new experiences I
>   will strive to grow my connections and understand those around me.

Should it state "will I" or "I will"? My guess is the former, but what are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I will" is more common. Subject-verb inversion e.g. "will I" is somewhat poetic and archaic, but not incorrect. It is a type of [anastrophe](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/anastrophe). Some may feel that it makes for a formal or literary style. As Grammarphobia says, "a usage that some readers find catchy may seem corny or pretentious to others". "Selfless duty" doesn't really mean anything - does your character mean selfless devotion to duty? I am doubtful about "devoted communication". The overall effect is of fine words that don't mean much. Perhaps those effects are intentional, to  portray the (perhaps priggish) nature of the character? The utterance quoted sounds like an oath, intended to be repeated by someone being inducted or sworn-in to some kind of office or priesthood.

[Follows the Subject](https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2016/05/inversion.html)

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct English.

- The first is more poetic, which might suit a "declaration" or
  "resolution".
- The second is more of a natural "statement" and more commonly used.

So for the purpose of making an **oath** or a **promise**: the first sentence is better.